# Dynamic binding using dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I know how to do Fibonacci series recursively, that's pretty simple:

```
def F(n):
  if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return k * F(n-2) + F(n - 1)
```

I do know however that this is extremely inefficient since it must calculate the same values again and again. A way around this is to somehow store values as you go along. Say you want the 20th value. Once you've calculated what F(13) is, its value can be stored and called directly rather than going through all the recursion levels to get the same answer.

Dictionaries are an obvious solution to this issue. However, my answer involving a dictionary does not work.

```
U = {1:1, 2:1}
def F(n):
  global U
  if n in U:
    return U[n]
  else:
    U[n] = F(n - 2) + F(n - 1)
```

Once this code is run just print U[n].

I've run through the logic multiple times and everything seems fine, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

whenever I try a number greater than 3. I don't see how a `None` should ever be returned, but I concede that I may be missing some sort of nuance about dictionaries that's causing the issue.

Comment: `global` isn't needed because you are not changing _which object_ `U` references. You are changing the _content_ of that object

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return` statement in the `else` clause.

```
def F(n):
  global U
  if n in U:
    return U[n]
  else:
    U[n] = F(n - 2) + F(n - 1)
    return U[n]
```

Or simplified:

```
def F(n):
  if n not in U:
    U[n] = F(n - 2) + F(n - 1)
  return U[n]
```

(`global` is not needed.)

Comment: Cripes, it's always the little things. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way using the fact that mutable defaults are only initialized once

```
def F(n, U={1: 1, 2: 1}):
  if n not in U:
    U[n] = F(n - 2) + F(n - 1)
  return U[n]
```

This avoid having to have `U` in the global namespace

Answer (score 0):

- When `n` is not in U, you should also return `U[n]`

Just:

```
U = {1:1, 2:1}
def F(n):
    global U
    if n in U:
        return U[n]
    else:
        U[n] = F(n - 2) + F(n - 1)
        return U[n]
```

- For the `efficient`:

  - if you want do it once, your second way is sacrifice space, and get time, I can't tell which is better in real dev environment.
  - if you want get the U[n] many times, store by a `U` is better

So if you want to store the value, maybe:

```
U = {1:1, 2:1}
def F(n):
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        U[i] = U[i - 2] + U[i - 1]
    return U

fb = F(10)

print fb[3]
print fb[5]
print fb[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) you might use functools.lru_cache (>= python 3.2). It does exactly what you want, except you don't need to modify the function and create additional data structures.

```
import functools

MAX_CACHE = 10**7

@functools.lru_cache(MAX_CACHE)
def F(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return F(n-2) + F(n - 1)
```

`MAX_CACHE` is the number of most recent calls to memorize.